# Creating multiple selection lists based that display an image based what you select

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a project where a user can select options from three sections on a webpage. Red Wine, White Wine, and Rose. Within those sections, they can choose from a drop-down menu that provides different wines within the category of flavor.

For example, Red Wine wine would allow you to choose from three flavors, white wine would allow you to choose from three other flavors, etc.

The issue I'm having is that whatever section I make last, is the only one that changes. If I go to change the wine selection under red it changes the rose section.

HTML

```
<div class="vl3"></div>
<div class="vl4"></div>

<div class="redwine">Red Wine<br> </div>
    <div class="redwineselect">
          <form action="purchase.htm" method="post"><br>
            Select Your Red...<br><br>
            <img src="merlot.png" id="redSelect" height="400px"> <br>
            <select name="redList" onchange="displayImage(this);">
                <option value="merlot.png">Merlot</option>
                <option value="pinot_nior.png">Pinot Noir</option>
                <option value="cabernet_red.png">Cabernet</option>   
            </select>
        <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Quantity" required size="8"><br><br>
        <button type="submit" class="submit">Purchase</button>
`     </form>
    </div> 



<div class="whitewine">White Wine<br></div>
    <div class="whitewineselect"> 
        <form action="purchase.htm" method="post"><br>
            Select Your White...<br><br>
            <img src="pinot_grigio.png" id="whiteSelect" height="400px"><br>
                <select name="whiteList" onchange="displayImage(this);">
                    <option value="pinot_grigio.png">Pinot Grigio</option>
                    <option value="riesling.png">Reisling</option>
                    <option value="chardonnay.png">Chardonnay</option>
                </select>
            <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Quantity" required size="8"><br><br>
            <button type="submit" class="submit">Purchase</button>
        </form>
    </div>



<div class="rosewine">Rose Wine</div>
    <div class="rosewineselect">
        <form action="purchase.htm" method="post"><br>
            Select Your Rose...<br><br>
            <img src="grenache.png" id="roseSelect" height="400px"><br>
                <select name="roseList" onchange="displayImage(this);">
                    <option value="grenache.png">Grenache</option>
                    <option value="mourverde.png">Mourverde</option>
                    <option value="pinot_rose.png">Pinot Rose</option>
                </select>
            <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Quantity" requried size="8"><br><br>
            <button type="submit" class="submit">Purchase</button>
        </form>
     </div>
```

JavaScript

```
function displayImage(elem){var image=document.getElementById("redSelect");image.src=elem.value;
}

function displayImage(elem){var image=document.getElementById("whiteSelect");image.src=elem.value;
}

function displayImage(elem){var image=document.getElementById("roseSelect");image.src=elem.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try different method names

```
<div class="vl3"></div>
<div class="vl4"></div>

<div class="redwine">Red Wine<br> </div>
    <div class="redwineselect">
          <form action="purchase.htm" method="post"><br>
            Select Your Red...<br><br>
            <img src="merlot.png" id="redSelect" height="400px"> <br>
            <select name="redList" onchange="displayRedImage(this);">
                <option value="merlot.png">Merlot</option>
                <option value="pinot_nior.png">Pinot Noir</option>
                <option value="cabernet_red.png">Cabernet</option>   
            </select>
        <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Quantity" required size="8"><br><br>
        <button type="submit" class="submit">Purchase</button>
`     </form>
    </div> 



<div class="whitewine">White Wine<br></div>
    <div class="whitewineselect"> 
        <form action="purchase.htm" method="post"><br>
            Select Your White...<br><br>
            <img src="pinot_grigio.png" id="whiteSelect" height="400px"><br>
                <select name="whiteList" onchange="displayWhiteImage(this);">
                    <option value="pinot_grigio.png">Pinot Grigio</option>
                    <option value="riesling.png">Reisling</option>
                    <option value="chardonnay.png">Chardonnay</option>
                </select>
            <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Quantity" required size="8"><br><br>
            <button type="submit" class="submit">Purchase</button>
        </form>
    </div>



<div class="rosewine">Rose Wine</div>
    <div class="rosewineselect">
        <form action="purchase.htm" method="post"><br>
            Select Your Rose...<br><br>
            <img src="grenache.png" id="roseSelect" height="400px"><br>
                <select name="roseList" onchange="displayRoseImage(this);">
                    <option value="grenache.png">Grenache</option>
                    <option value="mourverde.png">Mourverde</option>
                    <option value="pinot_rose.png">Pinot Rose</option>
                </select>
            <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Quantity" requried size="8"><br><br>
            <button type="submit" class="submit">Purchase</button>
        </form>
     </div>
```

```
function displayRedImage(elem){var image=document.getElementById("redSelect");image.src=elem.value;
}

function displayWhiteImage(elem){var image=document.getElementById("whiteSelect");image.src=elem.value;
}

function displayRoseImage(elem){var image=document.getElementById("roseSelect");image.src=elem.value;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much. Sorry if this was a dumb question, I'm just starting with JavaScript. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your three functions have the same name, so they are overriding each other. Give each of them a different name and it will work.